# How to formally prove $f(x)\geq g(x)$ and $g(x)\geq C$ does not necessarily imply the minimum value of $f(x)$ is $C$?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I am looking if there is a formal mathematical proof for this claim-

> $f(x)\geq g(x)$ and $g(x)\geq C$ does not necessarily imply the minimum value of $f(x)$ is $C$.

where $C$ is a constant.

For eg.$f(x)=a^2\sec^2 x+b^2\csc^2x=a^2+b^2+a^2\tan^2x+\cot^2x.$Thus by AM-GM $f(x)\geq(a+b)^2$.

However (wrongly) this can be done like this-

$$a^2\sec^2 x+b^2\csc^2x\geq2\sqrt\frac{a^2b^2}{\sin^2x\cos^2}=\frac{4ab}{\sin2x}$$ and max$(\sin2x)=1$.So min of $\frac{4ab}{\sin2x}=4ab$ and thus $f(x)\geq4ab$.

However this is incorrect because of the statement I set out to prove.I know a counterexample is enough proof for disproving something.However is there any way to show this formally by proper mathematical statements?

Comment: A counterexample is a proper mathematical statement (and you can just take $g=C+1$ and $f= C+2$ as constant functions).

Comment: @Thomas I know but is there any other way?Or should I make this a *big list* with all unexpected places where people get this error?

Comment: won't your example hold true if a=b?, regardless there is not an error, the inequality is still valid, but it may not be the best you can do

Comment: "I know a counterexample is enough proof for disproving something." This is not quite correct. "something" must be a "for all-statement". And then a counterexample is not enough, but _required_ for a disproof.

Comment: English note: you put a space after a period. "Like this. This is good."  "Not like this.This is incorrect."

Comment: Anyone please... Why did this post get downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $P$ doesn't necessarily imply $Q$, you simply need to give an example of $P$ where $Q$ doesn't hold. We can express this formally as

$$\neg (P\to Q)\iff\neg (Q\lor \neg P)\iff\neg Q\land P$$

where the first holds by definition of $\to$ and the second by distribution of $\neg$ over $\lor$ and the Law of Double Negation. I hope this clears up your confusion.

As mentioned in the comments, proofs of this are quite easy. Let $f(x)=x^2$ and let $g(x)=-100$. Then $f(x)\geq g(x)\geq -100$, but the minimum of $f$ is $0$.